# Local JVMs not able to perform HTTP calls on themselves to 0.0.0.0

Tags: java, docker, http, confluent-schema-registry

In a Java integration test I am starting a Confluent Schema registry with [`io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.RestApp`](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/core/src/test/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/RestApp.java). The registry is then used in the integration test.

When the integration test is run on GitLab CI or locally with the `maven:3.6.3-jdk-11` Docker image, the test is working.

However, when I run the test outside a Docker image with me local OpenJDK 11 or AdoptOpenJDK 11 installation, I get timeouts when accessing the local Confluent Schema registry.

```
18-08-2021 16:04:16.490 DEBUG [main] io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest:165 - Sending POST with input {"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"AdAuditKey\",\"namespace\":\"audit\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"adId\",\"type\":\"long\"}],\"connect.name\":\"audit.AdAuditKey\"}"} to http://0.0.0.0:28081/subjects/audit.AdAuditKey/versions
18-08-2021 16:04:16.491 TRACE [main] sun.util.logging.internal.LoggingProviderImpl$JULWrapper.log:141 - ProxySelector Request for http://0.0.0.0:28081/subjects/audit.AdAuditKey/versions
18-08-2021 16:05:16.507 ERROR [main] io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest:199 - Failed to send HTTP request to endpoint: http://0.0.0.0:28081/subjects/audit.AdAuditKey/versions
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:240)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1181)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1075)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1009)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1356)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1331)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:195)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:252)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:352)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:344)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:330)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:142)
```

Even performing a simple HTTP `GET` call results in an error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)

    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:608)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:557)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:182)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1592)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at IntegrationTest.ad stream topology should still work on restart of Kafka(AdStreamTopologyIntegrationTest.kt:268)
```

However, I can send a HTTP `GET` request with Postman to `http://0.0.0.0:28081/subjects/audit.AdAuditKey/versions` and get a valid HTTP response.

Why are the JVMs on my local system somehow not able to access itself via HTTP?

Comment: I don't know how you managed to **send** request to `0.0.0.0`. It is special IP. No one can have it. Do you mean `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: No, it's really `0.0.0.0`. 

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is special address. It means: all interfaces. Try to use specific interface.

Comment: I've never seen 0.0.0.0 as a host before.  You'll see 0,0.0.0 in routing tables, but that means (default).